# save the text file using date and time in r

Tags: r, datetime, logging, text-files

I'm want to save my program logging in a text file using R. I was able to save my entire logging in the text file. However, the challenge is text file name should have date and time. for example:

```
file1<- function(x){
flog.info("hi",name = 'trail')
summary = summary(x)
mean = mean(x,na.rm=T)
outpurt = list(summary,mean)
return(outpurt)
}
```

calling this function
    files = file1(airquality)

since, i need to add date and time
    Curr_date = (Sys.time()
appender function is used, in order to save the logging(file.info mentioned above).
    flog.appender(appender.file(sprintf(paste0(Curr_date,'.log))),
    name='trail.io')

you can see that, i was trying to use paste0 function in order to get the text file name with date and time. nothing works

Comment: kindly mention how to save the text file with date and time

Answer (score 2):

```
filename = paste(gsub(":", "-", Sys.time()),"_file.txt",sep="")
# [1] "2016-12-29 00-49-08_file.txt"
# to write the content to a .txt file with the above filename
write.table("your content", file = paste0("D:/", filename))
```

Comment: @NirmalS does it answer your question?

Comment: not really. Actually,I need the file stored in file.appender function

Comment: flog.appender mentioned earlier

Comment: @NirmalS I'm not much aware of `flog.appender()` function. So you might have to give me more info on this function? which package does it belong to?

Comment: i got file.append() but unaware of `flog.appender` and `file.appender`.

Answer (score 1):

Did I understand the problem correctly?

```
x = as.character(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))    
filename = paste(x,"_file.csv",sep="")
filename = gsub(":","-",filename)
filename = gsub(" ","_",filename)
```

Comment: hi, flog.appender() comes from futile.logger package. It will append all your logging information  and stores in a text file. for example :

Comment: flog.appender() comes from futile.logger package. It will append all your logging information  and stores in a text file.  You can see previous code, where i have mentioned flog.info. For each function I will write that logging information and each time when i call it, the logging information will be stored in a text file.  In flog.appender we can mention the file name as we like.However, I want my file name to be stored with date and time which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save the file with date and time. The appender function. flog.appender() should be used first and then we should use flog.info() inside every function.

```
result<- function(x1,y){
require(futile.logger)#package name
x=  Sys.time()
flog.appender(paste(x1,y,format(x,%y-%m-%d %I %p"),".log",sep ="")) #save file with date and time. for futile.logger see r bloggers.
}
```